# Burn the tag "hygeine" as it is wrongly spelled?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags

Shouldn't [hygeine](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygeine) be burned as it is wrongly spelled? There already does exist another synonym, namely [hygiene](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the aforementioned tags are already synonyms of the preferred tag, [personal-care](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-care), as shown on https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags/personal-care/synonyms. Since this had been a common misspelling, I think it's better to leave it as a synonym. *No questions are tagged with [hygiene] or its misspelling.*

No question can be tagged with the misspelled tag. If attempted, [personal-care](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-care) will be used instead. More info on how synonyms work can be found [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Comment: If this was something like color vs colour I would keep the common misspelling, but isn't keeping the hygeine-tag just wrong?

Comment: @holroy No question can be tagged with the misspelled tag. If attempted, [tag:personal-care] will be used instead.

Comment: @Mooseman, would you mind editing your above comment into your answer? Synonyms can be hard to understand, and, even though you posted a link, not everyone will read it. Your comment is a clear, concise explanation of what happens when we try to use a synonym. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Done. Thanks!

Comment: Er... don't you think it would be better for the world as a whole if you took this tiny opportunity to make people conscious of the fact that they misspelled "hygiene" instead of silently leading them to believe they spelled it correctly? SE sites are supposed to be a slightly higher quality than the rest of the internet.

Comment: @JasonC But by quietly correcting them by having the misspelled tag as a synonym we prevent the tag from existing again. We keep the "slightly higher quality" by pointing users back to the correct tag.

Comment: @JasonC what do you suggest? Unsynonymizing and putting a big all-caps "do not use" sign all over the tag wiki excerpt? People don't read tag wiki excerpts, the effect will be usage of the tag you want gone.

Comment: @JanDvorak The excerpt would became orphan without any tagged questions, as well.

Comment: AKA prone to death by roomba, then possible to be recreated again, and even without the wiki warning?

Comment: @JanDvorak Exactly!

Comment: @Mooseman Can mods blacklist tags? Then when a user types "hygeine" in the box, they won't be presented with a tag suggestion, won't be able to create it, and will be forced to either not use that tag or retype with the correct spelling.

Comment: @JasonC That would have to be done by a cm. And, to reiterate, the user will be redirected to the correct tag, so there is no reason to do so.

Comment: @Mooseman Bah. Sounds like I'll just have to be content to grumble about this one to myself when I try to fall asleep tonight. >:(