# Remove or clarify tags "cleaning" and "cleanliness"

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there a reason why both [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) and [cleanliness](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleanliness) exist?

I do see why tags like [holiday](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holiday) and [chanukah](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanukah) and [easter](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easter) coexist, but shouldn't tags which only vary in word type be simplified into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to [your earlier question](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2530), [cleanliness](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleanliness) is a synonym of [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning). Please see https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags/cleaning/synonyms. *No questions are tagged with [cleanliness].*

Comment: Just trying to comprehend where the limits go. Because to me these are so similar that it doesn't make sense to keep both. Whilst "food" and "cooking" are different alternatives, and in my head makes more sense to keep as synonyms. Is there a point in keeping very similar synonyms?

Comment: @holroy Keeping synonyms prevents the tag being created again, redirecting the user to the correct tag instead.

Comment: In addition to your comment on my other thread, regarding the main tag being used if someone tries to use the synonym, it makes a little more sense to me to keep both. (Even though I kind of still think it would be nicer with just one!)

Comment: @holroy Most users won't even see the second tag though, unless they try to use it.